# Javascript101 help | API | stuck

Tags: javascript, api, pushbullet

Per Pushbullet API doc I need: Header as: 'Access-Token: o.I'veLearnedNotToPost' 'Content-Type": "application/json' Url is https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me

Problem with my code (don't laugh too hard) is that it only returns "Retrieving information for o.I'veLearnedNotToPost"

Front end code needs to take token from user input text element and put it in backend code (getuser.jsw) to fetch User Info. But the issue is that it's not - nothing except the placeholder text appears in the textbox element (id #result)

Side note: $w is Wix's write to element

```
// FRONT END CODE
import {getUserInfo} from 'backend/getuser';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    console.log("Retrieving information for " + $w("#sendToken").value);

  getUserInfo($w("#sendToken").value)
    .then(usInfo => {
      ($w("#result").text) 
              });
}
```

```
//BACKEND CODE
import {fetch} from 'wix-fetch';


export function getUserInfo(token) {
    let atoken = token;
    let url = "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me";
      console.log("Retrieving information for  " + atoken);


   return fetch("https://api.pushbullet.comm/v2/users/me", {
  headers: {
    "Access-Token": atoken,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }

  .then(response => response.json())
})}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Greatly appreciated!
-Malc

Comment: I think it may be something with the way my Header is sending? That's an un-educated guess however. But thats what my gut says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Access-Token value is double quoted, try without.

Comment: Unfortunately it did the same thing. 
Thank you for the suggestion. I am open to any and all other ideas too!!

Comment: Updated code to reflect Gabriel Lopes advice. Still does the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: you have unclosed braces


  return fetch("https://api.pushbullet.comm/v2/users/me", {
    headers: {
      "Access-Token": atoken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}

Comment: When you log atoken before return, it's undefined or what?

Comment: Weird, the brackets are closed in the code but didn't paste to here for some reason. I also tried removing the [0] as I don't believe the fetch brings back an array. It should return User Info in json format. 
I'll report the updated code.

Also, atoken comes from the user input in a text element id #sendToken

Comment: I guess the main problem to solve is how do I get what is returned from the fetch, which is the User Info, displayed in textbox element id #result.
I'm unsure how to properly code the console stuff to take and display to an element

Comment: it seems that you're returns a function, try to fetch and return response, inside of then. Like this.

Fetch(URL, {
Header {
  Access-token: atoken
}}
.then(response => return response.json())

Comment: I plugged this code in (with the correct header) and I get Parsing error: Unexpected token {

Comment: I think i made a mistake, the correct code is 

https://jsfiddle.net/biutas/qL6y149g/1

Comment: Ok great! I think we're making progress... no error codes. But it still doesn't display anything except the placeholder text in my #result textbox. Could you take another glance at my front end code to see if it meshes well with the new backend code?

Comment: Yeah, sure, inside the getUserInfo then, usInfo receive the response as JSON, so you you have to set input value as usInfo.name, for example. 

In Jquery you do like this

$("#result").val(usInfo.name); 

I don't know the $w function, but probably is the same.

Comment: not sure if I put it in correctly...
```
import {getUserInfo} from 'backend/getuser';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
    console.log("Retrieving information for " + $w("#sendToken").value);

  getUserInfo($w("#sendToken").value)
    .then(usInfo => {
      ($w("#result").value(usInfo.name)) 
              });
}
```
I get an error warning that says ""value' does not exist on '#result'"
I get a Wix Help Message over UserInfo that says "usInfo: wix_users.User.UserRole
An object returned by the getRoles() function representing a user's roles."

Comment: Gabriel Lopes, I put in:
```
import {getUserInfo} from 'backend/getuser'; 
 
 export function button1_click(event, $w) { 
 console.log("Retrieving information for " + $w("#sendToken").value);
 
  getUserInfo($w("#sendToken").value) 
  .then(usInfo => {import {getUserInfo} from 'backend/getuser'; 
 
 export function button1_click(event, $w) { 
 console.log("Retrieving information for " + $w("#sendToken").value);
   getUserInfo($w("#sendToken").value) 
  .then(usInfo => {
 $w("#result").value = usInfo.name;
        }); 
 }
```
I got error: 'value' does not exist on '#result'

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!!!! YAAAAAAYYYYY!!!! Thank you soooo much Gabriel Lopes!!!! I so appreciate you!!!!!!!
This is my first ever code =D I feel like a million bucks - thank you again!!

Comment: I had to do one minor edit to the code you gave, it should've been .text vs .value
```
$w("#result").text = usInfo.name;
```

Comment: Awesome! it's the best feelling, isn't? I'm curious why you're using wix library, it's a wix website?

Comment: It indeed is! Now to learn more! Wix is a website builder like WordPress and the like.